# How to calculate the accuracy of a data using a particular classifier?

Tags: java, data-mining

I have a data set needs to calculate the accuracy of it using KNN classifier, I have tried to do that using the below code but it does not work.could someone state why? 
Actually I need to calculate the Acc from weka inside java

```
private void Fitness(){

            double Acc = 0.0;
            double  tp=0;
            double tn=0;
            double fp=0;
            double fn=0;
            Acc = (tp + tn)/ (tp + tn + fp + fn);
}
```

Comment: Do you just call the function like that ? You are basically assigning Acc = 0/0 which is wrong (you cannot divide by 0). You need to get the value of all 4 variables (tp,tn,fp,fn) and then give them to the method

Comment: thank you @OsumanAAA.. that what I am looking for.. how can i calculate the four varibles?

Comment: If you are using the Weka package in Java, there should be a method you can call to calculate the accuracy of your classifier. Did you train a classifier using KNN in weka ?

Comment: this question is weird...it's obvious that you have to count the true positives etc. before you can compute the accuracy. I'm not sure whether you even know what *true positive*, etc. mean - otherwise you'd know that it's just checking the result of the classifier with labeled data

Comment: yes @OsumanAAA I have trained the classifier as follows  Classifier ibk = new IBk();
            ibk.train(trainingExamples)

Comment: @hudasaid please show more of the code you used to train. Also, more info about the dataset and how you split it can be useful

Comment: `private double fitness(double  tp, double tn, double fp,  double fn){
            return (tp + tn)/ (tp + tn + fp + fn);
}` Is this what you are trying to do ?

Comment: the main issue is, he doesn't know how to get `tp, tn, fp, fn` which is quite trivial if you understand the basics of a classifier. Indeed, this is only possible during training a classifier by means of comparing the labelled data with the output of the classifier.

Comment: Yes you are right@AKSW. suppose I am newer in machine learning and tell me how to get the four mentioned values ( ttp, tn, fp, fn)

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning , calculating the accuracy is ,

```
number of correct predictions / total number of predictions
```

And the error margin is given by ,

```
number of wrong predictions / total number of predictions
```

Suppose ,I have made 10 total predictions out of which 2 were correct whereas 8 were incorrect.

Then Acc = 2 / 10 , error = 8 / 10